# FireBase iOS SDK & User Data/Cache

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

1. Run App in the iOS Simulator
2. Go through the login flow and login
3. Stop App and Remove App from the iOS Simulator
4. Run App and notice that the cache persists; FirAuth.auth()?.currentUser is the user that I previously logged in with before removing the app.

My assumption that by removing the app from the simulator enables me to start from a blank slate next time I run is not correct.

Can somebody please explain how/why the cache persists?

Answer (score 0):

`Firebase` manages this internally. The user which you get from `FirAuth.auth()?.currentUser` has nothing to deal with cache. So, even you delete the app from your simulator you will get `currentUser`.